# Remote to instance of SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i would like to remote from my house to my office in my instance of SQL Server but i have a trouble ,we have the primary server that has a public IP ,in this server there is installed a SQL Server Instance,i can connect on it just input in my Sql Server the "IP:1433" but my purpose is to connect in the SQl Server instance situated in my computer office and tried some way around but not luck ,then i would ask if you have any suggestion then i will try it .

Thank you so much for your attention

Cheers

Comment: Not related to programming in any way.

Comment: Is the SQL port forwarded to your desktop in the router?

Comment: @Arvo YEs thanks a lot for that...i modified it :)

Comment: @Alejandro no, it is not forward,anyway in the main server the port to connect to SQL SERVER  is  the same in my computer "1433",then you suggest me to change the port of SQL Server in my computer to 1434? Correct me if i wrong :)

Comment: It is not related to programming, like I said - this is simple network administration issue. You have to ask your company sysadmin forward some external port (other than 1433; 1434 is good enough) to your workplace PC port 1433 and then you have to access port 1434 from your home PC.

Comment: Changing the port will not have any effect, as the forwarding in the router still points to the main server, not to your computer. For a direct connection, there is no way other that changing the router setup. Workarounds may include a VPN as Ahmed Fayed suggests, tunneling over SSH if you have it setup in you home, or something like Hamachi or even TeamViewer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a vpn connection and then use your PC local IP inside the company